# Where do websites get UK addresses from?

Tags: database, search, lookup, street-address

When you have to enter an address lookup table on Amazon or another website (talking about UK specifically) where does the site get that info from? Is there a .gov table of everyone's addresses or does the website themselves have a database all them all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes in the UK the Royal Mail has a PAF, Postcode Address File, that they license out for use to address validation providers. You can read more about it on the [PAF website](https://www.poweredbypaf.com/)

There are similar databases in other countries as well